# Geek for geeks method to find height of BST

Tags: java, algorithm, queue, binary-search-tree

I copied this code from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-method-to-find-height-of-binary-tree/

I can't understand the part where Dequeuing all nodes of current level and Enqueue all  nodes of next level is happening

```
// An iterative java program to find height of binary tree

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

// A binary tree node
class Node {

    int data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(int item) {
        data = item;
        left = right;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {

    static Node root;

    // Iterative method to find height of Bianry Tree
    int treeHeight(Node node) {
        // Base Case
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Create an empty queue for level order tarversal
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList();

        // Enqueue Root and initialize height
        q.add(node);
        int height = 0;

        while (1 == 1) {

            // nodeCount (queue size) indicates number of nodes
            // at current lelvel.
            int nodeCount = q.size();
            if (nodeCount == 0) {
                return height;
            }

            height++;


/* 

This is the part where I'm very much confused , I can understand that the peek out the 1st node in queue to newnode and removes the 1st node in queue .. 


The part I can't understand is why we add nodes to that 1st position and decrease nodeCount at the end of each loop just for running the while loop until queue gets empty ??? 


So won't we have 0 as q.size() value later ??? I'm damn confused guys !!! Help me  !!! 

*/

            // Dequeue all nodes of current level and Enqueue all
            // nodes of next level
            while (nodeCount > 0) {
                Node newnode = q.peek();
                q.remove();
                if (newnode.left != null) {
                    q.add(newnode.left);
                }
                if (newnode.right != null) {
                    q.add(newnode.right);
                }
                nodeCount--;
            }
        }
    }

    // Driver program to test above functions
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.root = new Node(1);
        tree.root.left = new Node(2);
        tree.root.right = new Node(3);
        tree.root.left.left = new Node(4);
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(5);
        System.out.println("Height of tree is " + tree.treeHeight(root));

    }
}
```

Comment: what's your specific question?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the comments make it cleared:

```
        // Dequeue all nodes of current level and Enqueue all
        // nodes of next level
        while (nodeCount > 0) {

            //make a copy of the node at the top of the queue 
            Node newnode = q.peek(); 

            //remove the node to be checked from the queue so it will not be checked again
            q.remove();

            //since node was removed, update the number of nodes to be checked
            nodeCount--;

            //check top node is connected to other nodes 
            if (newnode.left != null) {
                q.add(newnode.left); //add left node to queue to be checked
            }
            if (newnode.right != null) {
                q.add(newnode.right);  //add right node to queue to be checked
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks bro :) , just the explanation i was hopping to get

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Consider voting it.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we had a tree with `n` nodes in the next layer. So `nodeCount` is `n`.

The while loop will iterate through the first `n` values in the queue. Recall that queues are [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), so only the first `n` nodes will be popped off. The new nodes being added in are not added to the first position as you wrote, but to the last position (queue, not a stack).

So, the loop will only run through `n` nodes, leaving what is remaining in the queue as the next layer of nodes.

---

For example: Say you have `3` nodes as follows:

```
Removed: none
Queue: ['level_a_1', 'level_a_2', 'level_a_3']
```

In this situation, `nodeCount` is `3`. As we enqueue new elements, they get added to the end:

```
Removed: 'level_a_1'
Queue: ['level_a_2', 'level_a_3', 'level_b_1', 'level_b_2']
```

But, as you can see, the remaining `2` elements to be removed are still from the previous layer.

Comment: thnx bro , i know this concept but my doubt was different :) .. it's cleared by #c0der  now :)